# iMacros: Script: Split array on &nbsp;

Tags: arrays, string, split, imacros

**iMacros Script**
I Need to extract 3 radio buttons text, evaluate it against a stored option. So that the correct selection can be made. There are only 3 buttons but the options are dynamic. I can extract text, and if split can eval it with Gematria. My issue is splitting the text so it can be eval'd. The text is separated by

`&nbsp;`

**Example of the extraction** SQF BOX

```
SQF&nbsp;BOX&nbsp;
```

**Html I am pulling from**

```
        <td class="evenBand" width="60px" align="left">
        <input type="radio" name="ordUom0" id="ordUomR0" tabindex="1001" value="SQF" onclick="checkHSUom(0,'SQF','BOX','','SQM',32.93,1.0,1712.36);"
>SQF&nbsp;
    <br>
        <input type="radio" name="ordUom0" id="ordUomI0" tabindex="1002" value="BOX" onclick="checkHSUom(0,'SQF','BOX','','SQM',32.93,1.0,1712.36);"
>BOX&nbsp;
        <input type="hidden" name="orderedUom" id="orderedUom0" value="" 
    <="" td="">
        </td>
```

**DOES NOT WORK**

```
SET !VAR3 EVAL("'{{!VAR2}}'.split(' ')[0].trim();")
SET !VAR5 EVAL("'{{!VAR2}}'.split(' ')[1].trim();")
SET !VAR6 EVAL("'{{!VAR2}}'.split(' ')[2].trim();")
```

**DOES NOT WORK**

```
SET !VAR3 EVAL("'{{!VAR2}}'.split('&nbsp;')[0].trim();")
SET !VAR5 EVAL("'{{!VAR2}}'.split('&nbsp;')[1].trim();")
SET !VAR6 EVAL("'{{!VAR2}}'.split('&nbsp;')[2].trim();")
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this will be helpful to you:

```
SET !VAR3 EVAL("'{{!VAR2}}'.split(/\s+/)[1];")
SET !VAR5 EVAL("'{{!VAR2}}'.split(/\s+/)[2];")
```